# HTML elements in VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'm building a web scraper that has navigated me to the following website based on data that I've copied and pasted into the Box Office Mojo search bar: http://www.boxofficemojo.com/search/?q=Rogue%20One:%20A%20Star%20Wars%20Story

What I need to do now is be able to click on that link to go to the Rogue One mojo website, and then scrap a bunch of data from it.  I just don't know how to interact with this HTML element.  The Link I need has the following HTML code:

<*a href="/movies/?id=starwars2016.htm">Rogue One: A Star Wars Story

any ideas??

My complete code thus far is below:

---

```
Dim objIE As New InternetExplorer
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument

With objIE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "http://www.boxofficemojo.com/"
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Set Doc = objIE.Document
End With

Set oSearch = Doc.getElementsByClassName("nl_link")(3)
Set oSearch = oSearch.getElementsByTagName("input")(0)
    oSearch.Value = Sheets("2016").Range("c3").Value
    Doc.forms(0).submit

Do While objIE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop
```

Comment: I believe that you can use "IE.Navigate" to find / go to different hrefs. After you find the href by name or class ID, you can append the href to get the full URL and then make IE navigate to it. For example:
     
`IE.Navigate "https://www.linkedin.com/in/meek-mill-8165b769/"`

I haven't given this a try yet, but my first references for scraping HTML with VBA is WiseOwl Tutorials. There are 3-4 really good videos that are uploaded to his channel on YouTube. For example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dShR33CdlY8

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is somewhat sloppy because I am not too familiar with this site and because I don't have time to write you extensive code for free, but this worked for me so I will let you build off of it if needed:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim objIE As New InternetExplorer
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument

    With objIE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "http://www.boxofficemojo.com/"
        Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Set Doc = objIE.Document
    End With

    Dim oSearch As HTMLDivElement

    Set oSearch = Doc.getElementsByClassName("nl_link")(3)
    Set oSearch = oSearch.getElementsByTagName("input")(0)
        oSearch.Value = Sheets("2016").Range("c3").Value
        Doc.forms(0).submit

    Do While objIE.Busy Or objIE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Dim oRslt As Object, Element As Object, myLink As Object

    Set Doc = objIE.Document
    Set oRslt = Doc.getElementById("body").getElementsByTagName("a")
    For Each Element In oRslt
        If Element.outerHTML Like "*/movies/?id=*" Then   'Found ID # of movie
            Set myLink = Element
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Element

    objIE.Navigate myLink

End Sub
```